# Nested query cache redirects in Apollo

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I've got a question about `cacheRedirects` in Apollo, I've got an overview of items and a detailview. I'd like the detailview cache to be redirected to an item from the overview (like [the book example](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html#cacheRedirect) in the docs).

The only thing is that the thing I'd like to redirect to can only be queried from inside a bigger parent query.

So expanding the books example it'd be like:

```
# for all books
library (id: ID) {
    books (params) {
        id
        title
    }
}

# for a single book
library (id: ID) {
    book (id: ID) {
        id
        title
    }
}
```

What would I redirect to if I'd like to fetch a single book?

I don't think I could do this, because I'm actually fetching a library in order to fetch a book:

```
cacheRedirects: {
    Query: {
        book: () => {
            // return book id from cache
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to redirect a query for a book (through a `library`) to the data for a book? Or am I thinking about this in the wrong way?

Comment: Thanks for posting this, it helped me. I'm curious though, in your example, why couldn't you have queried a single book directly? Is it that ids are not unique between different libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't know you could also resolve types directly so in this case:

```
cacheRedirects: {
  Library: {
    book: (_, args) => toIdValue(dataIdFromObject({ id: args.id, __typename: 'Book' }))
  }
}
```

Should work to redirect to a cached book from a library.